# Windows Mobile development in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just pulled the 2010 ultimate from MSDN, and I see there's no "Smart Device" options anymore. Does anybody knows how to enable it, or how to install it?

Sincerely,
Yvan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to various sources in the net Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support Windows Mobile 6.5 development (see [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/windows-mobile-development-in-vs2010.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/nunoluz/archive/2009/05/21/visual-studio-2010-will-not-support-smart-device-development.aspx) for example). Of course there might be an SDK available in the future. For now, you need to use Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Is it still not possible to use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate to program  on a Window Mobile 6.5 Device?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any up-to-date information. My guess is that it is still not possible. Only a guess though.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can with windows phone SDK7.1 You just need Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and download the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)