# Does VS2010 support Windows-mobile projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have Visual-studio 2010 prot and I am trying to create a Windows-mobile or Windows-CE project, but I don't see how to do it.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658868/windows-mobile-development-in-visual-studio-2010 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010

Comment: How is Incognito's answer the marked one? It does not answer the question you asked. Codekaizen's answer is far more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS 2010 there is Visual Studio Phone. You can check [VS 2010 Phone](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/04/12/visual-studio-2010-rtm-and-the-windows-phone-developer-tools-ctp.aspx).
You can find there a lot more for windows phone development.

Answer (score 4):

No, Window Mobile development is not available in VS 2010. You must use VS 2008.

If you want to do Windows Phone 7, you can (and must) use VS 2010, but it is not the same as Windows Mobile (i.e. Smart Device) development on the Compact Framework.

Here's the official word: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, it is unsupported, you have to use Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008.

On Visual Studio 2010 you can target Windows Phone 7 applications: http://www.microsoft.com/express/phone/

Answer (score 0):

You can go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote to have Microsoft add Compact Framework Support for Visual Studio 2010.