# Developing apps for Windows CE .NET 4.2 with VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-ce

Is it possible to develop apps for Windows CE .NET 4.2 in Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7? Because I had several problems trying to use VS2003 and eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0... Thanks

Comment: It's not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080618/does-vs2010-support-windows-mobile-projects/3080627#3080627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can definitely use Studio 2005 and *probably* Studio 2008 (I've not tested CE versions earlier than 5.0 that I recall) with native code. Managed code will be fine but it will require manual deployment of the CF to the device before debugging (Studio '08 will puke trying to deploy it).

Comment: Thanks @ctacke, so Studio 2005 would be recommended? Does it have any issue while running in Windows 7?

Comment: I'd try Studio 2008 first.  It definitely works, even under 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: I use VS2008 for native CE development targeting CE 4.2, 5.0 and 5.2. It deploys and works just fine.